# Which DNS records should i have for several subdomains and naked domain?

Tags: dns

We have 3 sites/apps hosted on 3 different locations (IP addresses):

- **Angular app:**

app.domain.com on IP 1.1.1.1

- **Web Service:**

api.domain.com on IP 2.2.2.2

- **Web Sit/Blog:**

domain.com AND www.domain.com on IP 3.3.3.3

So, we want domain.com to go to www.domain.com.

What is the right, best practice way to solve following case?
What DNS records should we have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google recommends 301 redirect (see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633). Therefore it is neceessary to use `URL` record. See https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/ for example.
If your NS-server does not support URL records then you need to add URL rewrite rule on your web-server. In this case:

1. In first, you should create two same A-records for domain.com and www.domain.com on NS-servers. Also you can use CNAME-record instead of second A-record.
2. In second, configure redirection on your hosting server (3.3.3.3). In [this article](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/non-www-to-www/) considers the similar solution for IIS or Appache web server..

Comment: If my DNS doesn't support URL records, on which web-server, out of three, should i put redirect rule? and how will request reach that particular server in the first place?

Comment: If I understand your question,  the domain.com and www.domain.com is hosted on single web-server and you want to all requests sended to domain.com will be redirected to www.domain.com. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. they are both on single web.-server with ip 3.3.3.3

Comment: I have updated my answer take into account your comment.